# HttpContext.Session.TryGetValue gives nonsense

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, session

I am starting to learn ASP.NET MVC. Now I am trying to create an application that supports personal accounts without class [Membership](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-Ru/dotnet/api/system.web.security.membership?view=netframework-3.5), class [FormsAuthentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.web.security.formsauthentication?view=netframework-4.8&viewFallbackFrom=windowsdesktop-7.0) etc. I was surfing the programming forums to solve the problem below for nearly 4 hours, now I'm exhausted...

If the user doesn't check the "Remember" box in the login form, my app saves username to the current session:

```
HttpContext.Session.Set("authentication", Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(username));
```

And when the user tries to open the personal account page, my app tries to get the saved value from session:

```
if (!HttpContext.Session.TryGetValue("authentication", out username)) {
    return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
}
```

It displays the value using function [Controller.Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.content?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2). **But when I enter username "SNBS" and click "Login", it displays the following nonsense:**

*The personal account interface will be here. Your username: UwBOAEIAUwA=*

***Note***: the rest of login/logout functionality works properly: when I try to open personal account page without authenticating, it redirects me to login page, etc.

I suppose the problem is caused by encodings, as `HttpContext.Session.Set` receives a byte array in parameter `value`. I tried changing `Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes` to `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes` and to other encodings, but it just changed the nonsense displayed. I also tried using `System.Convert` — it gave the same result. Now I don't know what to try, as session usage includes not more than five lines of code and there is simply nothing that could work improperly...

Comment: Its base64 encoded. Convert.FromBase64String helps.

Comment: **Note**. The `Convert` class sometimes gives some errors that are not easy to fix. I faced one of them (about unexpected padding characters, though there aren't any padding characters in the string I gave it). So I would replace it with `Encoding.UTF8` which works properly.